# UWP Windows 10: Is there a variable counting app starts?

Tags: uwp, windows-10, counter, startup

do UWP apps for Windows 10 contain a variable counting the number of startups? If yes, what is the name of this variable?
I want to perform an event after a certain number of app starts. Otherwise i need to develop a startup Counter manually.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could work:

```
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        //Count App starts
        object Counter = localSettings.Values["AppStartCounter"];

        if (Counter != null)
        {
            localSettings.Values["AppStartCounter"] = (int)Counter + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            localSettings.Values["AppStartCounter"] = 1;
        }
     }
```

Comment: I wanted to suggest the same. But i suggest you move this to `App.xaml.cs` instead of `MainPage.xaml.cs`.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing like this in the SDK, you have to implement it yourself.